# RegEx not replacing apostrophe in url

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a url that has information added from variables for account names, address, etc. I'm using a regex variable `var regex2 = /[;\\\\\/:*?"$=()<>|&']/g;` and `replace()` to replace any special characters from the url that is created. All the characters are removed when the url is created except the apostrophe.

Here is the part of the url that is being replaced using the regex variable. Is there something missing?

```
if('{!account}' != ''){
             url += '&CF00NG0000008ODGm=' + '{!account.Name}'.replace(regex2, "");
```

Comment: So, you have `var regex2 = /[;\\\\\/:*?"$=()<>|&']/g;`, where one ``\\`` is redundant. Are you sure there are straight and not smart/curly apostrophes? Try `var regex2 = /[;\\\/:*?"$=()<>|&'‘’]+/g;`

Comment: Please provide an [mcve], **including** sample input (a good question includes sample input, the code, and the desired output).  It will get you much more / better assistance...

Comment: Is `{!account.Name}` something that gets replaced by a framework of some kind? You should tag the question with the framework, in case it's relevant.

Answer (score 0):

I added JSENCODE() within the merge field {!account.name}. This added an escape character in front of the apostrophe when the account name was added. Sonny's Barbecue is added to the javascript code as Sonny\'s Barbecue.